# NodeJS Not Receiving BigCommerce Webhooks

Tags: node.js, ssl, bigcommerce

During development, I tunnelled all the my product/created and product/updated post requests through ngrok to my localhost and everything was working fine, but once in awhile I noticed it might miss a hook and not receive it, but this problem happens almost all the time in production for me on both my stores.

The moment I switched everything to production, I deleted the old hooks, re registered them using the live domain, and when I request a list of registered web hooks, I can see that they are active from the "is_active" flags. But for some weird reason, when I go through the same workflow as I did during development, I don't see any of the post requests being received by my server at all, but once in awhile, I might see 1 get received and my server will do its thing with that hook.

I thought it might have had something to do with my SSL/TLS setup, so I went to https://www.ssllabs.com/ to do a quick test. Everything was graded A, the only thing that I noticed was that my certificate #2 or my CA bundle was not trusted for whatever the reason. So I actually removed the CA cert from my server and only used my RSA/Cert instead for the credentials. However, in another PHP app that we made for BigCommerce, it is using the same type of certificate generated as the one that I'm using right now through LetsEncrypt, and in that PHP app all the hooks are received properly.

Given all this, I still can't seem to quite pinpoint where the problem lies. When I tunnelled everything through NGROK, I registered the hooks to the https url given to me, https://xxxx.ngrok.io -> localhost. Then on my node server, I created a server using http instead of https to avoid 502 bad gateway conflicts. So the only differences is me switching from using ngrok to my own https using https.createserver.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

```
https
  .createServer(
    {
      key: app.get('RSA_KEY'),
      cert: app.get('SSL_CRT'),
      ca: app.get('SSL_CA')
    },
    app
  )
  .listen(HTTPS_PORT, async function() {
  ... some code  
})
```

app is express.router()

Comment: Are you still using the ngrok url? or do you have a new one for your app?

Comment: Nope! I've already deleted the Ngrok hooks and re registered the hooks using my live callback uri and I confirmed this by getting a list of my registered hooks

Comment: Are you okay with providing your store_hash and times you setup the webhook here? You can also post this question directly in our forums as well. https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/

Comment: Yup! Started a discussion on the forums right over here:

https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/feed/0D51B00004Rgrqx?t=1529430675211

Comment: Awesome! We'll get you sorted over there.